# {basePath} creates a folder named {basePath} issue

Tags: assets

just built a blog with craft, and I got some issues with assets pathing.
In the general.php I put

```
return array(
    'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/images',
            'baseUrl'  => 'https://site.com',
        )
);
```

But when I put {basePath} to assets path, the system creates a {basePath} named folder in root and looks for the image folder there. Also the {baseUrl} is looking like this in the code:

`https://site.com/{baseUrl}/images/image.jpg`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is using Craft 3, you should [use aliases](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases).

In your `config/general.php` add:

```
'aliases' => [
    'web' => 'https://site.com',
    'webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web'
],
```

Then in your Control Panel, under Settings → Assets → Images, set your **Base URL** to `@web/images` and **File System Path** to `@webroot/images`.

Comment: Thank you so much Oli, this resolved the issue.